# why the integral $\int_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^8 + \sqrt{x}}$ is converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, infinity

How to show that this integral $\int_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^8 + \sqrt{x}}$ is divergent? I try using $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^8}$ and then $\lim_{x \to {\infty}} \frac{\frac{dx}{x^8 + \sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1}{x^8}}$ = L (L-constant), but  $\int_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^8}$ is divergent, so my answer is diverge, but the correct one is converge,

Why?

Comment: $x^8 \ll \sqrt{x}$ when $x$ is close to $0$.  So in $x^8 + \sqrt{x}$, the $\sqrt{x}$ term dominates.

Comment: What you wrote is meaningless ... $n=0$ and $dx$ do not go together in an integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x\geq 1$, you should use
$$
\frac1{x^8+\sqrt{x}}\leq \frac1{x^8}
$$
and for $0<x<1$, you should use
$$
\frac1{x^8+\sqrt{x}}\leq \frac1{\sqrt{x}}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^8+\sqrt{x}}~dx \leq \int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{x}}~dx+\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^8}~dx <\infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Close to $x=0$, you have by Taylor
$$\frac{1}{x^8+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-x^7+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ So, no problem.